# How to disable autoComplete in React form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a weird bug on my React form and the username and the password gets filled automatically when I go to that page.

My `Input` component:

```
 return (
    <div
      className={
        error ? [styles.form_group, styles.error].join(" ") : styles.form_group
      }
    >
      {placeholder && (
        <div
          ref={refPlaceholder}
          className={styles.placeholder}
          style={props.defaultValue ? { display: "none" } : null}
        >
          <label htmlFor={name} className={styles.label}>
            {placeholder}
          </label>
          {props.required && <span className={styles.star}>*</span>}
        </div>
      )}
      <input
        ref={refFormControl}
        {...propsInput}
        autoComplete="off"
        className={styles.form_control}
        name={name}
      />
      {error && (
        <span ref={refFormError} className={styles.error}>
          {error}
        </span>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

and I'm just using it in `div` like:

```
<div>
          <Input
            id="username"
            type="text"
            name="username"
            placeholder="Username"
            error={getInputError(errors, "username")}
            onChange={(e) => onChangeFormValue("username", e.target.value)}
          />
</div>
```

Values of username and password gets filled automatically.

[image]

I have tried following, but none worked:

1. add `form` and set it to `autoComplete: 'off'`
2. `autoComplete='new-password'`
3. added `hidden` input value on top of `form`, but didn't work either

Comment: What browser are you using? Is it the same in other browsers? Are you using a password manager, and if so do you still have the problem without it?

Comment: Some browsers do not listen to this feature anymore https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#:~:text=If%20a%20site%20sets%20autocomplete%3D%22off%22%20for%20username%20and,the%20user%20visits%20the%20page.

Comment: make sure that your email and password is not stored in browser history..

Comment: This is now becoming browser-dependant feature. Firefox will not respect this rule on forms as well as Opera and Chrome I think.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I'm using Chrome, but it is same in Firefox.

Comment: I have password manager and passwords stored, but I'm not quite sure how this is causing the issue as `autoComplete` should have done the job?

Answer (score 0):

HTML's tags are not case sensitive, but attributes are.

In your code you have `autoComplete="off"` with a capital letter C.

Try with `autocomplete="off"` (all lower-case).

Comment: Did you actually check that question is related to React?

Answer (score -2):

You have to wrap the input tag into the form:

```
 <form autocomplete="off">
      <input type="text" />
    </form>
```

Also, you can try

```
<input name="my-field-name" autoComplete="new-password" />
```

Comment: OP mentioned that they have tried both of these, literally just read the question.

Comment: @Nijat Mursali mentioned that he already tried those options. Please edit your question with new information or delete it. In the future please read questions carefully.